# Safari for Windows - disable certain plug-ins

Tags: windows, plugins, safari

I just can't find a way of doing this - in Safari for Windows (5.1.7) I would like to disable certain plug-ins, but I can only see how to disable them all (from Preferences/Security-> Enable Plugins) - can I not switch them on and off individually?
I have read about physically deleting files from a Safari folder within Windows Explorer but I'm not convinced about this (and there are no files in there that match what I am trying to disable anyway). 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get rid of individual plugins in Safari is to physically delete (or move them to another folder) from the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Safari\Plugins` folder.

If you say you've already checked and what you're looking for is not in that folder, are you it's a plugin and not an extension? You should be able to manage extensions individually in the preferences option within Safari.

If your plug-in doesn't appear in the folder, it shouldn't load anyways. If you can't find it there and it does load, I think your best option would be to uninstall and re-install Safari.

Sorry if this doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks for that. Within that folder all I have is JavaPlugin.jar and npJavaPlugin.dll - but when I list my plugins from Safari I have loads - Adobe Acrobat, Microsoft Office, Microsoft Windows Media Player, Quicktime, Shockwave Flash etc but nothing like this in my folder. Strange. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Do you know which specific plugins you want to disable? You can also disable them by finding the plugin within the program file. Example: Adobe plug-in at least for me is located `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\Browser\nppdf32.dll` If you remove this file your plug-in will not load

Comment: Although this will likely just cause an error to show up, if Safari tries to use the plug-in

Comment: Quick fix to remove plugin: rename plugin like X-np*.dll,